# Comment/uncomment line of JavaScript file with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, production, console.log

So, I have a project which is now in production. For the production deployment, I use this to hide all console logging:

```
console.log = function() {}
```

Obviously, I want to log stuff during development, though. We're using a node server, so ideally I'd like to just add something to the production script to uncomment this line. Is this possible?

Comment: There are much better ways of logging. Use a logger module such as [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston), app wide. Then you can configure the logger in any way, e.g to be silent when in production, or write to a specific file etc.

Comment: @S.D. I figured it was a question brought about by a poor process. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, there are far superior ways of doing logging and I'd strongly recommend you to invest a few hours to refactor how you do logging. It'll definitely be worth it in the end.

That said. Depending on your build system, there's a lot of solutions out there. Here's a just a few which will help you strip console statements if you you [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-debug), [Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-strip) or [Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip)